# How to insert radio button value into MySql

Tags: php, mysql

anyone can help me with this
thank you very much in advance

This is my save.php file

```
<?php

include('db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['Set1']))
{
    $Set1 = $_POST['Set1'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'evaluation' (A1) VALUES ('$Set1')");
}
else if (isset($_POST['Set2']))
{
    $Set2 = $_POST['Set2'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'evaluation' (A2) VALUES ('$Set2')");
}
else if (isset($_POST['Set3']))
{
    $Set3 = $_POST['Set3'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'evaluation' (A3) VALUES ('$Set3')");
}
else if (isset($_POST['Set4']))
{
    $Set4 = $_POST['Set4'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'evaluation' (A4) VALUES ('$Set4')");
}
//the code continue until A30..

?>
```

this is my radiobutton file

```
   <form action="save.php" method="post">
          <h3 style="text-align:center;">B. Kerja Berpasukan</h3>
          <table class="table table-condensed" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Bil.</th>
                <th id="th01">Kriteria</th>
                <th id="th02">Skala Kompetensi</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>1.</td>
                <td>Menunjukkan sifat-sifat bekerjasama seperti sedia 
              berkongsi maklumat dan kiraan yang telah
                    diperoleh/dilakukan</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r1" type="radio" name="Set6" value="1" 
required/>1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r2" type="radio" name="Set6" value="2" 
required/>2
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r3" type="radio" name="Set6" value="3" 
required/>3
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r4" type="radio" name="Set6" value="4"     
required/>4
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r5" type="radio" name="Set6" value="5" 
required/>5
                    </label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>2.</td>
                <td>Menunjukkan kesanggupan melaksanakan tugas dan 
             arahan/permintaan pegawai</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r1" type="radio" name="Set7" value="1" 
required/>1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r2" type="radio" name="Set7" value="2"  
required/>2
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r3" type="radio" name="Set7" value="3" 
 required/>3
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r4" type="radio" name="Set7" value="4" 
 required/>4
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r5" type="radio" name="Set7" value="5" 
required/>5
                    </label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>3.</td>
                <td>Sentiasa bertindak sebagai kumpulan seperti bersama 
               menyediakan/membantu
                    membuat tugasan/aktiviti</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r1" type="radio" name="Set8" value="1" 
required/>1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r2" type="radio" name="Set8" value="2" 
required/>2
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r3" type="radio" name="Set8" value="3" 
required/>3
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r4" type="radio" name="Set8" value="4" 
required/>4
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input id="r5" type="radio" name="Set8" value="5" 
required/>5
                    </label>
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```

my database name is 'SPPI'
table to save the radiobutton value is'evaluation'
the table has a field from A1 to A30

Comment: please mention about what is your problem.are you getting any errors..??

Comment: Shift your SQL Connection to `MySQLi`

Comment: you need to insert each radio value into each row or all radio value into 1 row what you want ?

Comment: your php variables within the `INSERT` statements are in single quotes and will only be read as a string. what are the `(A1)`, `(A2)` etc sections to the table names?

Comment: use backticks for column name and table name instead of single quotes if put single quotes it consider as string "INSERT INTO `evaluation` (`A1`) VALUES ('".$Set1."'')"

Comment: Btw html `id` attributes have to have unique values.

Comment: you need to store each value in new row or everything in one row ?? @JasonJoslin

Comment: Joshua you need to go away and learn some basics of MySQL and PHP before asking a question here, there's no sign you've made any attempt to research the multitude of similar questions already on StackExchange.

Comment: @JYoThI He can use the variable directly in the string since it's in double quotes.

Comment: @inarilo do single quotes work inside double quotes with out escaping? eg `"Select blah from blah where blah = \'$variable\' "`?

Comment: @JasonJoslin you only need to escape them if you are using the same character as the enclosing character, otherwise php will treat it as the end of the string. So you don't need to escape single quotes inside a string enclosed by double quotes or vice versa. Thus `"Select blah from blah where blah = '$variable' "` will work, though it is better to enclose variables used thus in curly brackets, `"Select blah from blah where blah = '{$variable}' "`.

Comment: my problem is, I want to save the radio button value that has been selected by the user. i dont have any error

Answer (score 1):

first of all do you have submit for all the set that your want to post ??If don't have it please add submit into your code 
for example :
change the value into your desired value .

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes on your question. Please google these notes for details solutions to each point, as appropriate:

- PHP `include`s do not need brackets. Remove them.
- **STOP** using `mysql_` functions they are DEPRECATED and have been removed in PHP7. You should be using `MySQLi_` functions or better yet, `PDO`. Research these.
- You need to learn to use **Prepared Statements** or to ***fully clean your user input***. Currently nefarious user input can easily take over and destroy your MySQL table(s).
- You need to close your HTML `<form>` tag. Your form tag *should* also contain a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` element (*as well as probably an* `accept-charset="UTF-8"`)
- You very probably need to fundamentally rethink your MySQL table structure and data architecture.
- As suggested by [`nixxkenzou`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43341246/3536236) you need to actually submit your HTML form for your server to process the data (as to which radio buttons where selected, etc.)
- PHP `else if` can be reduced to `elseif`
- Read up and make full use of [PHPs extensive error reporting system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php?rq=1). Which will guide you to avoiding tedious syntax errors.
- HTML `id` tags need to be unique on a page, if the id is referenced by anything (javascript, CSS, etc.) and there's more than one, it will cause you issues.

Good luck.

Comment: Why would he need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data` when he has only radio buttons?

Comment: @inarilo not specifically for radio buttons but it's a good habit to get into for POST forms to use the correct defined encoding type.

Comment: If this was the only correct form then it would be the default, surely. I've never heard of this being required unless files are being uploaded.

Comment: @inarilo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: The accepted answer in that says what I said (in fact before commenting here I double checked and that was the question I read).